# Removed privileges from root user and can't access database

Tags: mysql, permissions

New to databases and accidentally removed privileges from root user; only privileges I currently have are USAGE and PROXY. This is a MySQL database that I access through HeidiSQL. Currently cannot access my data tables; is there a way to get these privileges restored? Did not create any other user accounts.

Comment: What privileges did the root user have and do you have the name of the root user? Since it is a root user i assume it has the highest of privileges so you can run mysql code to grant privileges: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO 'myuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION; See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016505/mysql-grant-all-privileges-on-database for more information

Answer (score 1):

You can use following steps to regrant root priviledge.

1. Shutdown `mysqld`.
2. Start `mysqld` with [`--skip-grant-tables`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-grant-tables).
3. Use `mysql` to connect `mysqld`. (Type `mysql` only, No need to input password `-p`, maybe No need to input username `root`, either)
4. `UPDATE mysql.user SET Grant_priv='Y', Super_priv='Y' WHERE User='root';`

   `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
5. Restart  `mysqld` normally.

Comment: How do I shutdown mysqld?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-startstop-excerpt/5.7/en/

Comment: I don't have shutdown privileges so I can't use the mysqladmin shutdown. I tried turning off MySQL using the "Services" menu on my PC, but when I try to restart with 'mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables -skip-networking' it tells me that it can't connect to server. Any ideas?